# Determine which dictionary an object came from

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, plist

I have a PLIST file that stores issue information. At the top is an array, and within that array there are dictionaries. Within each dictionary is a string called "Date" with different dates. I then display the date values in a table view.

I am able to determine the text of the UITableview cell tapped (and therefore the date string), but how do I then access the other values within the **same dictionary?** If the I know that the date string is February 16, 2012, how do I get the "Download URL"? Here is a picture of my PLIST:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be getting the indexPath from the cell that is tapped. The indexPath.row should give you an index number that you can use to get the correct dictionary from your array of dictionaries. If you are not already keeping this array, consider doing so if it's a manageable size.

```
NSDictionary *selectedIssue = [myArrayOfDictionaries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSSTring *downloadURL = [selectedIssues valueForKey:@"Download URL"];
```

Personally, I would never rely on the date being unique or formatted in any particular way.

Answer (score 2):

You can sort your array (Issue List) by the issues date before you init your TableViewController with that data and than use the NSIndexPath of the cell that was tapped.

To sort the array with the dictionaries use this snippet:

```
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date" ascending:YES];
[issues sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:descriptor,nil]];
```

After that you can use the indexPath like that:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *url = [[issues objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"download_url"];
}
```